# Datepicker select list overflow not working

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using `datepicker` but finding a problem, when trying to select the year or month with the select list the first time showing goes of on top and bottom with no scrolling available, after closing it and open it like 3 times it works as the example from the official page, I've been trying to find out if there is a problem with position or something but can't seem to figure it out, in the google inspector I see that every time I open it and close it, gets different height and top values.

[image: Example img]

My code for the input is this:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" type="text" class="validate datepicker" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")">
    <label for="DateOfBirth">* Fecha de <span id="texto-nacimiento">Nacimiento</span></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="helper-text red-text"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you plz add this into the code snippet and share so we can run and see whats going on?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this since it seems everywhere either Fiddle or CodePen seems to work fine, just want to see if someone has encountered something like this or if is some css problem.

Comment: Hmm I have not encountered this exact problem but generally in a situation like this, it could be because the list is inheriting height incorrectly and it is a styling issue. May be set this height relative to an immediate parent so that you can compute the height? Another pointer - check in the library if there is a computation for height you will need to revisit.